# Multiply a number by a ratio n times to achieve a desired number

Tags: math, logarithm, exponent

I'm trying to scale an image down in steps so as to avoid artifacts. I have an 800 square pixel image that needs to be scaled down to 100 square pixels. I want to perform the scaling in a variable number of iterations. So lets say that I want to go from 800 to 100 in 3 iterations. How do I find the ratio to apply to the image each time to achieve the desired size?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths.

Comment: Hmm, well math and programming are pretty interrelated.  The greater problem is a programming problem.  Doesn't that count for something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve a final ratio R, in N steps, then the ratio at each step would
be the N-th root of R, or equivalently, R^(1/N).  For your example, R=1/8, and N=3, so 
the ratio at each step would be (1/8)^(1/3), or 1/2.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> math.exp(math.log(100./800) / 3)
0.5
```